# Access an object property functionally

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing the following:

```
var item1 = new Object();
item1.name = 'a & b';
item1.description = 'Do a & then do b';
item1.untouched = 'Dont touch this';

var item2 = new Object();
item2.name = 'c';
item2.description = 'Do something else';
item2.untouched = 'Dont touch this';

uppercaseProperties = function( properties, obj ) {
    properties.forEach( function( p ) { obj[ p ] = obj[ p ].toUpperCase() } );
    return obj;
}

[item1, item2].map( function( item ) {
    return this.uppercaseProperties( ['name', 'description'], item );
}, this );
```

For brevity and expressiveness, I'd much rather use `map` instead of `forEach`, i.e. something like

```
uppercaseProperties = function( properties, obj ) {
    properties.map( function( p ) { return obj[ p ].toUpperCase(); } );
    return obj;
}
```

but that doesn't work, as it only returns the modified properties, not the entire objects. So what I'd need to do here is  functionally access `obj`'s member `x`. Now I could obviously write a function that does that, but I wonder if JavaScript does have anything native for that? (FWIW, [C++ has](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun_ref/).)

Comment: Not sure I get it, `Array.map` creates an array, and you seem to be creating an object, so why would you use `map` ?

Comment: Iterating a separate collection of keys and modifying the `obj` for each, what you have seems to be fine. Using `.map()` would create a `new Array()` with the results of `doSomething()`, typically used instead of modifying `obj`. Otherwise, what improvement are you hoping to see?

Comment: You need to state what your desired output will be, what are you trying to achieve? If your goal is to modify ``obj`` based on your array of properties than you have accomplished this. If your goal is something different then you need to state that.

Comment: Also, `doSomething(obj[x])` will immediately call that function. [You might want `doSomething.bind(null, x)` or something instead.](http://jsfiddle.net/5ezt6d3k/). Who knows.

Comment: Updated question with a comprehensive example for clarity.